# Fredholm index of invertible bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T: X \to X$ be bounded and invertible.

Is it true that the Fredholm index $\mathrm{ind}(T) = 0$?

Comment: yes, because both the kernel and the cokernel of $T$ are trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because both the kernel and the cokernel of $T$ are trivial.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that the kernel is trivial but why is it true that the cokernel must also be trivial? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: The cokernel is by definition the quotient space of $X$ by the range $R(T)\subset X$. Since $T$ is invertible, it follows that the range of $T$ is the whole $X$, $R(T)=X$, and hence $X/R(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: But the equivalence "surjective if and only if injective" for linear maps only holds in finite dimension. Why does injectivity here still follow even though $X$ is a possibly infinite dimensional Banach space?

Comment: The problem says that $T$ is invertible; this means $Ker T=\{0\}$ and $R(T)=X$ by definition

Comment: On the other hand if $T$ is only known to be injective, it may well  be not surjective; for example, the operator of multiplication by $x/(1+|x|)$ in $L^2(R)$ is injective but not surjective (range nonclosed)

Comment: Or the right shift operator in $l_2$: range closed but has codimension 1

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for giving these examples!